# Why Intl.DateTimeFormat produces different result in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, datetime, intl

I'm using Intl.DateTimeFormat to format dates and I noticed that different browsers produce different results.

I used the following code to format date with Estonian locale:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("et").format(new Date(2017,0,2))
```

Results I got:

- Edge HTML 14.14393: ‎**02‎.‎01‎.‎2017**
- Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (Windows): **2.1.2017**
- Chrome Beta 56.0.2924.59 (Android): **2017-1-2**

I'm quite unhappy with the result because I was hoping similar output. Why these differences exist and is it normal (expected)?

With locale *en* each browser gave same result (‎1‎/‎2‎/‎2017).

Comment: i18n databases are huge and not all engine builds include all of them. Furthermore, there can be minor differences between vendors since they don't necessarily use the same data.

Comment: To really ruin your day, try changing the interface language in Chrome. Swedish dates (locale = "se") will be formatted differently for each of these interface languages: English (US), English (UK), Swedish and Danish (there may be other variations, but that was enough testing for me). Why does the same method to return a locally formatted date return different results depending on the browsers own interface language? Intl is pretty useless the way it's been implemented so far.